# Make field Readonly or Non editable just by using RegEx

Tags: regex

Is it possible to make a field non editable just by using RegEx?

Thank You

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're talking about HTML, no. Regex simply matches string patterns, and nothing more. It can't prevent someone from editing an input field. It's not the right tool for the job.

You're likely looking for the `readonly` attribute for an HTML input.  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp